# AWS Glue Pyspark Transformation Filter API not working

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am new to AWS Glue and Python.  Trying to apply a Filer.apply function for a dynamicFrame datasource0 in filter3frame.  The job run failed and I am getting that filter_sex function is not defined in the logs.  Exact error: "NameError: filter_sex is not defined".  Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "amssurvey", table_name = "amssurvey", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")


filter1frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=lambda x:x['citizen'] in ["US"])

filter2frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=lambda x:x['count'] > 50)

filter3frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=filter_sex(datasource0))







filter1_op = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = filter1frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/filter1_op"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "filter1_op")
filter2_op = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = filter2frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/filter2_op"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "filter2_op")
filter3_op = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = filter3frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/filter3_op"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "filter3_op")
job.commit()



def filter_sex(item):
    if item['sex'] == 'Male':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it fixed.

As told by @QuickSilver, every function has to be defined before it is used.  Also, the dynamic frame has to be written like below.  filter_sex function where it is called need not be having a parameter.

```
filter3frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=filter_sex)
```

So the final working code is as follows -

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

def filter_sex(item):
    if item['sex'] == 'Male':
        return True
    else:
        return False



## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "amssurvey", table_name = "amssurvey", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "amssurvey", table_name = "amssurvey", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("nomber", "long", "nomber", "long"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("sex", "string", "sex", "string"), ("citizen", "string", "citizen", "string"), ("count", "long", "count", "long"), ("countstate", "long", "countstate", "long")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]


filter1frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=lambda x:x['citizen'] in ["US"])

filter2frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=lambda x:x['count'] > 50)

filter3frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=filter_sex)







filter1_op = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = filter1frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/filter1_op"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "filter1_op")
filter2_op = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = filter2frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/filter2_op"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "filter2_op")
filter3_op = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = filter3frame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/filter3_op"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "filter3_op")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining a func. why dont you try below code

```
filter3frame = Filter.apply(frame=datasource0, f=lambda x:x['sex'] > 'Male')
```

**Regarding the compilation error :**
 `filter_sex` should be define before it is used

Comment: Yes, but I want to write in a separate function and not a lambda function

Comment: I tried to define the filter_sex function right after the import statement, still I face another error ""TypeError:" 'DynamicFrame' object is not subscriptable".  Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry @kdkarthik I am not a Python expert but it seems that there is data type mismatch between input param of filter_sex function and the input which you are providing . Your function expects dataframe col I guess